# Import a Nest.js app as a simple Express middleware

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, middleware, nestjs

I've a Nestjs app (a Rest API) that I would like to import in another node module, as a simple Express middleware (not a Nest middleware). Actually I'm still not able to make it working.

```js
// main.ts  
// => The main file of my Nest app, this one is working properly.

import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

```js
// app.middleware.ts

import {Injectable, NestMiddleware} from '@nestjs/common';
import {NestFactory} from '@nestjs/core';
import {AppModule} from './app.module';
import {ExpressAdapter} from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import express, {Request, Response} from 'express';

const bootstrap = async () => {
  const expressApp = express();
  const adapter = new ExpressAdapter(expressApp);
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, adapter);
  await app.init();
  return app;
};

@Injectable()
export class AppMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
    return bootstrap();
  }
}
```

```js
// express-app.ts  
// => Here I'm trying to load my app through a simple Express middleware, but it doesn't works.

import express from 'express';
import { AppMiddleware } from './app.middleware';

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const app = new AppMiddleware().use(req, res, next);
  app.then(next);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`app running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

When running my app from `main.ts` it's working properly (all the routes are working and I'm getting the correct data). However when I try to run the app through `express-app.ts`, all the routes seems working (they are displayed in the terminal), but instead of returning a JSON object, in any case I'm getting this error:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>[object Object]</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Nest component versions:

```
- @nestjs/common: "^6.10.14"
- @nestjs/core: "^6.10.14"
- @nestjs/platform-express: "^6.10.14"
- express: "^4.16.4"
```

Comment: Why do you want to make your Nest server a middleware instead of having the Nest application run the express application by default?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I just upgraded an Express node module to Nest, and I want this module to remain compatible as an express middleware for some time.

Comment: Well, my proposed solution does work, however, I still don't see why you don't take the existing Express app and pass it as the parameter to the `ExpressAdapter` and let Nest be the top layer. It would make porting code easier and more understandable, but to each their own

Comment: Yes, you are right, this is something that I am now considering in light of your post, and with the performance issues we can notice. Thank you for your help, this allows me to move forward on a better architecture addressing my concerns.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While I don't condone the use of Nest as a middleware itself, it is possible. Using a basic set up from a `nest new express-server -p npm` to create the new NestJS application, and setting up a small express server with `src/server.ts` I was able to get the following code working.

#### app.middleware.ts

```js
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { ExpressAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

const bootstrap = async (express: Express.Application) => {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, new ExpressAdapter(express));
  await app.init();
  return app;
}

@Injectable()
export class AppMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {

  constructor(private expressInstance: Express.Application) {}

  use(req: any, res: any, next: () => void) {
    console.log('In Nest middleware');
    return bootstrap(this.expressInstance);
  }
}
```

#### app.controller.ts

```js
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

#### app.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  getHello(): string {
    return 'Hello World!';
  }
}
```

#### app.module.ts

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

#### server.ts

```js
import * as express from 'express';

import { AppMiddleware } from './app.middleware';

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const nest = new AppMiddleware(app).use(req, res, next);
  nest.then(() => {
    next();
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    next();
  });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});
```

#### Build command

```sh
npm run build
# mapped to nest build
```

#### Start command

```sh
node dist/server.js
```

#### Test command

```sh
▶ curl http://localhost:3000
Hello World!
```

#### Console Log

```sh
Listening on port 3000
In Nest middleware
[Nest] 24235   - 02/18/2020, 8:05:44 PM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 24235   - 02/18/2020, 8:05:44 PM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +15ms
[Nest] 24235   - 02/18/2020, 8:05:44 PM   [RoutesResolver] AppController {/}: +3ms
[Nest] 24235   - 02/18/2020, 8:05:44 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 24235   - 02/18/2020, 8:05:44 PM   [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +2ms
```

Keep in mind a few things:

1) with this approach, unless you cache your Nest server, you **will** build a new Nest server on each request, which will only slow your project down more as you grow with the Nest side of things.

2) You could instead pass your existing express server to the `ExpressAdapter` as you are partially doing in your existing code and start the server from the Nest `app.listen()` function instead. Just make sure to remove any error handling middleware as it will start to conflict with how Nest handles responses. You should instead move those functions to ExceptionFilters.

3) One of the errors in your `app.middleware` is that you are creating not only a new Nest instance on each call, but a new express instance too, which could really be confusing the node server.

4) The error that was coming in as `[Object object]` in case you were wondering, was a standard Express error `Cannot GET /`. Dunno why it was serialized strangely, but a `JSON.stringify()` in the catch helped resolve it.

Overall, I would not recommend this approach **but** it is possible to do.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, well detailed, explained and instructive. I just upgraded an Express node module to Nest, and this adapter allows remaining compatible as an express middleware for some time (hopefully short). Indeed, start a new Nest instance on every request isn't an ideal scenario. Thank you for the points you mention at the end of this post! I'm also considering making the main Nest app running through an aws lambda instead, so the performance is definitely something I'll look closer.

Answer (score 2):

**@Etienne** your `bootstrap` function is actually fine as it is and you can use it directly in `express-app.ts`. Advantages:

- No new Nest instance per request
- Independent configuration for each express app

**app.middleware.ts**

```js
import {NestFactory} from '@nestjs/core';
import {AppModule} from './app.module';
import {ExpressAdapter} from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import express from 'express';

export const bootstrap = async () => {
  const expressApp = express();
  const adapter = new ExpressAdapter(expressApp);
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, adapter);
  await app.init();
  return app;
};
```

**express-app.ts**

```js
import express from 'express';
import { bootstrap } from './app.middleware';

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

bootstrap().then(expressApp => {
  app.use(expressApp);

  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`app running on port ${PORT}`);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it’s not exactly the answer to the question, but I’d just like to leave an example using this middleware.

For my context, I thought it was okay to put everything in the nest, instead of putting the nest in the express.
I needed to put all my standard express application, working with the node, with no special conditions, just join the 2, this was my scenario.

I just took the global settings, like body-parser and dotenv and put it in my main file.

#### src/main.ts

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import { useExpress } from './workspaces/poc/server'
import { TodoModule } from './workspaces/todo/todo.module'
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';

// was in src/workspaces/my-legacy-app/server.ts
dotenv.config()

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(TodoModule);
  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  // was in src/workspaces/my-legacy-app/server.ts
  // also did not know how to resolve the issue of types, so use "any"
  useExpress(app.getHttpAdapter() as any)

  await app.listen(3000,() => {
    console.info(`App runnning on port: ${3000}`)
  });
}
bootstrap();
```

My old legacy main file

#### src/workspaces/legacy-app/server.ts

```js
import { validatorMiddleware } from './middlewares/validator.middleware'
import { logMiddleware } from './middlewares/log.middleware'
import { userRouter } from './routes/user.route'
import { Express } from 'express'

export function useExpress(server: Express){

  server.use(validatorMiddleware)
  server.use(logMiddleware)
  server.use('/user', userRouter)
  
  // commented because the server will go up here more, but just to show that it was the same way as in express
  // server.listen(
  //   process.env.PORT,
  //   () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${process.env.PORT ?? 3000}`)
  // )
}
```